# Android fragments: open context menu programmatically

Tags: android

I need to open context menu by one click on view. I have already register view for context menu.

When I used activity I simply called openContextMenu([view registred for context menu]); but fragment hasn't this method.

What must i do to open context menu by one click in fragment?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`getActivity().openContextMenu` should work.

Comment: what view would you pass to openContextMeun?

Comment: and for opening optionsMenu? `getActivity().openOptionsMenu()` didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Find your view or just inflate, and then save it

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    View myView = view.findViewById(R.id.view);
```

Then you can open context menu using

```
view.showContextMenu();
```